# Join query of two databases in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, join, codeigniter-2, multiple-databases

I need to write a join query of two tables from two databases and fetch the joined data.
For eg, consider I have a database db1 which has some tables named companies, plans, customers. Suppose I need to join the two tables companies and plans with another table 'cdr' on another database db2 by grouping them using a similar column.

The query which I'm running right now is given below:

```
function get_per_company_total_use ($custid)
        {         
                 $this->DB1->select('ph_Companies.CompanyName');
                 $this->DB1->where('ph_Companies.Cust_ID', $custid);
                 $this->DB2->select_sum('cdr.call_length_billable')->from('cdr');
                 $this->DB2->group_by('cdr.CompanyName');
                 $this->db->join('Kalix2.ph_Companies', 'Kalix2.ph_Companies.CompanyName = Asterisk.cdr.CompanyName');
                 $query = $this->db->get();
                 if($query->result()){
                     foreach ($query->result() as $value) {
                         $companies[]= array($value->CompanyName,$value->call_length_billable);
                          }
                     return $companies;
                 }
                 else 
                     return FALSE;
        }
```

But my query is not fetching the data and throwing an error. This same query, I have run on a single database and is working. But I need help to find how this can be done with two databases.

Comment: "But my query is not fetching the data and throwing an error." What error is it throwing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just give the following if you need to join two database tables:

```
function get_per_company_total_use ($custid)
        {         
                 $this->db->select('Kalix2.ph_Companies.CompanyName');
                 $this->db->where('Kalix2.ph_Companies.Cust_ID', $custid);
                 $this->db->select_sum('Asterisk.cdr.call_length_billable')->from('Asterisk.cdr');
                 $this->db->group_by('Asterisk.cdr.CompanyName');
                 $this->db->join('Kalix2.ph_Companies', 'Kalix2.ph_Companies.CompanyName = Asterisk.cdr.CompanyName');
                 $query = $this->db->get();
                 if($query->result()){
                     foreach ($query->result() as $value) {
                         $companies[]= array($value->CompanyName,$value->call_length_billable);
                          }
                     return $companies;
                 }
                 else 
                     return FALSE;
        }
```

Here actually you need not give the connection variable DB1 or DB2, just give $this->db.

Comment: what if databases are run on different machines?

Comment: I have same case, both database are on different server. then how can i get the records.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having table x in DB1 which contain id, name and y_id.
In DB2 there is a y table with id and name

so if you need to get name of x and y in a same query the here is your answer:

```
    $db = $this->load->database("DB2", TRUE);
    $DB = $this->load->database("DB1", TRUE);
    $DB->select('x.name as name1, y.name as name2');
    $DB->from('x');
    $DB->join($db->database.'.y','x.y_id = y.id');
    $res = $DB->get();
```

Comment: what if both databases are on a different server. then how can I get the records.

Comment: @Jitendra You have a solution on different server? Thanks