# how to join tables of two different databases

Tags: codeigniter

I want to convert my query in codeigniter,this query uses two databases.this work in mysql but I can't write this query in codeignitor.mysql query is as following:

```
$sqlStr = "select s.*,b.booking_status as bstatus,b.booking_id,e.mfg_date,e.ownership,e.evaluation_category,e.booking_id,pb.booking_cancel_status,pb.unverified_cancel_status
                from avstonau_poc.tbl_exchange e
                join avstonau_poc.tbl_stock s on e.exchange_id=s.exchange_id
                join avstonau_maruti_pune.tbl_booking_maruti pb on pb.booking_id=e.booking_id
                join avstonau_poc.tbl_booking b on b.stock_id=s.stock_id
                ";
            $result = mysql_query($sqlStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Join query of two databases in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159618/join-query-of-two-databases-in-codeigniter)
Check it once if it works
I am also facing similar issue
Add second database credentials on database.php
Like

```
$db['db2']['hostname'] = 'ip/Rds';
$db['db2']['username'] = 'root';
$db['db2']['password'] = 'password';
$db['db2']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['db2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db2']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['db2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['db2']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and put

```
$CI = &get_instance(); $this->db2 = $CI->load->database('db2', TRUE); 
to use it as  $this->db2->select('...');
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but you will need to have the same MySQL user allowed to access both databases.  Once you do this you can use $this->db as normal but you need to specify the database name in the query.  Note that you only have to specify the database name for the second database and do not have to do this for the default database.
Example:

```
    $this->db->select('table_from_default_db.id, 2nd_db_name.table_from_second_db.name');
    $this->db->from('2nd_db_name.table_from_second_db');
    $this->db->join('table_from_default_db', 'table_from_default_db.id = 2nd_db_name.table_from_second_db.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```